# Smart edit is unstable after Spartacus storefront upgrade

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

We recently upgraded our Spartacus storefront app from 1.4.4 to **3.2.2**

After upgrade Smart edit is unstable, it is not working properly.

Edit options are not working. Sometimes edit options getting enabled.

Storefront rendered in SSR.

Our Hybris version is **1905.19**

Please help us to resolve it.

Comment: Do you see any errors? can you confirm you followed these steps https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/core/src/global-message/http-interceptors/handlers/bad-gateway/bad-gateway.handler.ts? Did you take a look at our troubleshooting section for SmartEdit https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/smartEdit-setup-instructions-for-spartacus/#troubleshooting?

Comment: We already created a ticket for it: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/11683. Thanks